Captured Chagned Data through ADF in Azure Blob Storage
*Hi,
Our requirement is to apply CDC through ADF, source is Azure SQL and CDC destination is in Azure Data Storage container, We already implemented CDC through ADF and seems Changed Captured in Azure Container, but concern is, every operation creating separate log .csv file in container. Now, requirement is  to apply all the operation from those logs in a data bricks table to check the live updates in Data Bricks delta table. So please provide the assistance for the same as its the pain for us now.
*

I am still waiting for response, please let me know if there is any issue in understanding the concern

Do you want to update the same file everytime for its respective table change? If yes, how are you gonna use databricks in this? Can you explain the involvement of databricks in this? and what is your expected output?

Do you want to update the same file everytime for its respective table change?
[Comments]:Actually, our source system is having 55 tables in Azure Sql tables so we are planning to create an ADLS Gen2 where is going to maintain Bronze, Silver and Gold Layer and in Bronze layer we are going to maintain the raw data in Delta format the Silver and Gold will be having Delta Live table so what we are trying to capture the in Bronze like should have 55 files with latest records so apply CDC in ADF to Capture real time changes.

If yes, how are you gonna use databricks in this? Can you explain the involvement of databricks in this? and what is your expected output?[Comment]: Whatever raw data we have in Bronze layer or may be in stage layer through ADF along with all the CDC files should be correctly visible in delta table format like if we made 3 time modification in a single record so Delta table in Data Bricks should show the final version of the record instead of consideration a separate entery of every CDC file from stage folder. As planning to create some data marts in GOLD layer to connect with Visualizati.

[What is happening currently]: when we applied CDC via ADF then we are able to capture every performed operation over the table in a Azure container and every example make a new files like if we deleted a record then getting a new file with the same change if we are updating the records then also getting a new file. continued....

And when trying to access the same container via DataBricks note book via spark command so system considering every file is a normal source and getting all the entries in data frame instead having the latest updated one or last version of the entry so wondering how we can capture this CDC files in correct format in delta table

Sorry, my message was long so break in multiple comments, please have a look and let me know if making sense to try for the solution

Are you using the pipeline design same as your previous question? lookup -> for-each -> copy activity to Gen2? If not can you edit your question add your pipeline design?

We tried 2 approaches, 1 is the same pipeline which you asked and second is tried CDC through adf and saving files in a container to fetch in Databricks

So, considering the first approach, you know in which source tables the changes had happened and you want the same data in the target csv file, right?

Correct, like we have 50 tables then it should be only 50 files even when we have chnages and modification in a corresponding table then only it should be in underline file

I have tried your second approach using CDC and it seems currently, it's not supported to generate a single file in it as it is following spark architecture.
As you have list of source tables in which there is a change and an alerting system to trigger the pipeline, you can try the below workaround. But this method will copy total source table data after the change to its target file by overwriting the target file every time.
Create two datasets for both source and target. In the target dataset, create a dataset parameter filename like below.

Use this parameter in the file name as @dataset().filename.

Similarly, create a dataset parameter in the source SQL dataset and use it in the table name as @dataset().table_name.

Inside your For-Each, take a copy activity with above datasets as source and sink. In the source, give the current table name @item().table_name to dataset parameter.

Do the same in the sink as well but use this expression @concat(item().table_name,'.csv').

Initially, run this pipeline design for all source tables so that all the target tables for its respective source tables will be created and then modify it as per the change occurred tables list.
On every change in tables, the table names list will be given to the For-Each and data in its target file will be overwritten by its source table.

You can use these files in your databricks tables design later on as per your requirement.

Thanks for your response, do we have anything through which we can trigger this pipeline with the performed operation on source table e.g. ADF should have auto run based on activity performed on source tables. Secondly, is there any to perform only the incremental load after having a full load as tables volume is huge.

I have already mentioned that it will only work if you have an alert system that will trigger this pipeline. But You can use CDC to a temp location where it will generate part files upon the change. So, add a storage event trigger to this pipeline and in the path of that trigger give that temp location/part (file name starts with part). But this also copied all the tables even though you have triggered pipeline on right time. You need to find a way to get the table names which are changed. Also, Unfortunately, it can't perform incremental loading to Gen2 with this design.

One workaround for your scenario is have CDC for every table and give your table name as folder name. Even though CDC creates a new file every time, it will create only a part file and a success file. So, in databricks notebook, connect to Gen2 and have a loop to get all the part file paths of a table as an array and read that array paths as a dataframe. Then you can apply transformations and write these two your next layer. You need to do this for all of your tables(folders) in the same databricks code.

You can schedule this notebook from ADF using storage event trigger and pass the folder path using storage event trigger parameters to ADF pipeline.

You can append the new part file to the old dataframe as union.

Agreed, if someone updated a entry thrice then even though we triggered and placing union all on Gen2 to append so it will append all the 3 times updates as a insert entry if we don't have a key+ timestamp+ performed Operation Flag in the file to recognize. Correct?   Even same would be happening for deletion as well, a delete entry as well capture in the files so it will again consider as a insert entry. correct?

Yes, in the databricks instead of union you can try upsert to avoid the duplicates.

So, is the upsert will handle deleted items as well in files, and would be managing the final updates.

Yes, it can handle delets as well.

Thanks let us try the same approach, will let you know asap and thankful for your help.:)
